# Dealing with .net WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, html, .net

I want to deal with web-browser control in .net framework as follows,
Dividing html into pixels and plot any text or any picture over a certain known pixels.
as i have an image of hyper text (text and images) and the text written in a separate file (each word is saved with each position in the image and i want to make html document with the same layout of the picture using c#
how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Don't deal with web browser control. Deal with HTML instead.

Get HTML doc from browser control modify it. Use CSS for layout or for placing it on particular pixels and load modified HTML in web browser control.

Comment: could you explain how can i do this?
all what i know about HTML is a group of tags!!